# JavaFX mouse transparent is not working

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to understand the mouse transparency property.
This is an example code, is composed by 4 button
I'm want to make all button clickable, but i don't know how...

```
public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        ObservableList<Node> children = stackPane.getChildren();

        Button button = new Button("I'm not clickable");
        button.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        children.add(button);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
     // vbox.setMouseTransparent(true); If i put this here, nothing work
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(20);
        vbox.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        vbox.setPrefWidth(400);

        ObservableList<Node> vChildren = vbox.getChildren();
        vChildren.add(new Button("This"));
        vChildren.add(new Button("Button"));
        vChildren.add(new Button("Are clickable"));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
     // borderPane.setMouseTransparent(true); If i put this here, nothing work
        borderPane.setLeft(vbox);
        children.add(borderPane);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: If you make a container mouse transparent, nothing in the container (e.g. buttons will receive mouse events).  As far as I can see everything is working as it should...

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "clickable"? What is the code (without the `setMouseTransparent(true)` calls) not doing that you want it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, a big button with 3 buttons inside. But as I said, it doesn't make any sense at all. Not from coding, not from usability. But if you must, you must. Here's the code:

```
public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        Button bigButton = new Button("I'm not clickable");
        bigButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(e));
        bigButton.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        bigButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(bigButton);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(20);
        vbox.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        vbox.setPrefWidth(400);

        ObservableList<Node> vChildren = vbox.getChildren();
        Button button1 = new Button("This");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.consume();
        });
        Button button2 = new Button("Button");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.consume();
        });
        Button button3 = new Button("Are clickable");
        button3.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.consume();
        });

        vChildren.addAll(button1, button2, button3);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(vbox);

        vbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(bigButton.widthProperty());
        vbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(bigButton.heightProperty());

        bigButton.setGraphic(borderPane);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a node's mouse transparency to false, then it simply won't receive mouse events.

I created a small example for you to understand what the mouse transparency does.

```
public class MouseTransparency extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Rectangle outerRect = new Rectangle(100,100,200,200);
        outerRect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        outerRect.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2));

        Rectangle innerRect = new Rectangle(150,150,50,50);
        innerRect.setStroke(Color.RED);
        innerRect.setFill(Color.RED.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2));

        Circle circle = new Circle( 250, 250, 50);
        circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2));

        // mouse transparency checkbox
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox( "Enable Mouse Transparency");

        // bind inner rect mouse transparency to the checkbox value; in the end you'd rather use innerRect.setMouseTransparent(...); 
        innerRect.mouseTransparentProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());

        Label label = new Label("You clicked: ");

        // add event handlers
        outerRect.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> label.setText("You clicked: Outer Rectangle"));
        innerRect.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> label.setText( "You clicked: Inner Rectangle"));
        circle.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> label.setText( "You clicked: Circle"));

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll( checkBox, label);

        root.getChildren().addAll( vBox, outerRect, innerRect, circle);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you click the inner rectangle while mouse transparency isn't active, then it will receive events. If you activate the mouse transparency for the inner rectangle by selecting the checkbox, then the outer rectangle will receive the events when you click on the inner.

[image]

However, you should rather enable/disable buttons if your intended use case is buttons.

Comment: So there isn't solution for my problem? In swing i remember there was setOpaque and everything work great

Comment: Please answer the question in the comments above. What is your problem?

Comment: I have a big button on root of stage on this there is a borderpane, on the borderpane in the left there is a vbox, in the vbox there are 3 buttons, how can i make all this button receive mouse event?

Comment: Sorry, but 3 Buttons on 1 Button doesn't make any sense at all.